# Magento 2: Purpose of \Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleListInterface

Tags: magento2, module

I have seen `\Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleListInterface  $moduleList` implemented in a **custom module** like that

```
$this->_moduleList = $moduleList;
public function getExtensionVersion()
{
    $moduleCode = 'My_Module';
    $moduleInfo = $this->_moduleList->getOne($moduleCode);
    return $moduleInfo['setup_version'];
}
```

My question is, What is the **purpose of this interface** and which **methods we can invoke** using this interface?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose this class is to get the information about modules. Use these methods using ModuleListInterface.

```
  namespace Magento\Framework\Module;
  interface ModuleListInterface
   {
     public function getAll();
     public function getOne($name);
     public function getNames();
      public function has($name);
   }
```

[Documentation Link](https://www.magentoextensions.org/documentation/_module_list_interface_8php_source.html/)

Comment: what is getAll() for? and same like getOne,getNames,has

Comment: The methods do what their names suggest: `getAll` - retrieves you info about all installed modules, `getOne` - gets you info about a specific module, `getNames` gets you the names of the installed modules and `has` checks if a module exists without retrieving the info.